# MySQLi verify if a statment exist before fetching

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a basic mysqli prepared statement which is working fine

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $_SESSION['user_id'], $id_alerte, $id_roster);
$stmt->execute(); 
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
 ...
}
```

After the while loop I have some other code to add (mainly echo). When my statement is empty everything under the while is dropped (echos are not printed).
I would like to add a if condition to verify if the statement exist and if not skip the while loop. How can I do?

I tried

```
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {  
 my while loop
}
```

But it will not execute the loop.
ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysqli, if you want to use the result within the same mysqli object, you need to call `$stmt->store_result()`. (Noted in [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289) from php.net)

Your revised code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $_SESSION['user_id'], $id_alerte, $id_roster);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result(); 
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {  
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to do it but you need to wait a certain time to accept an answer. Now it is done. Thanks again and have a nice day